# Trying to run a for loop slicing an array each 30 spots

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

Im trying to slice an array on 30 at a time to send a call to an endpoint which can only recibe 30 codes at a time. Right now I have about 203 lines in the array. Everything is fine until the 4th round where I don't know why the indexes (init and endt) I've set up, get messed up and the slice no longer works which in turns makes the call to the endpoint impossible. Here is the code:

```
$arrcount = ceil(count($requestarr['SelectionDetails'])/30);

$init = 0;

if (count($requestarr['SelectionDetails']) > 30) {
    $endt = 29;
} else {
    $endt = count($requestarr['SelectionDetails']);
}

for ($i=0; $i < $arrcount; $i++) { 

    $request['SelectionDetails'] = array_slice($requestarr['SelectionDetails'], $init, $endt);

    $init = $endt+1;

    if (count($requestarr['SelectionDetails']) > ($endt+30)) {
        $endt += 30;
    } else {
        $endt = count($requestarr['SelectionDetails']);
    }

    //call to endpoind and other code here....

}
```

The `requestarr[]` has the whole 203 indexes and the `request[]` contains the 30 indexes slice sent each loop. Its worth noticing that my array has "custom" keys that are tracking numbers from FedEx. At the 4th loop, the init turns into 120 and the endt turns into 113. Im not sure how or why this happens. Needless to say the next 3 for loops the endt gets reduced by 7 then by 34 and finally by 1. There is no code where the endt should be decreasing. So I'm not sure how this is happening. Any ideas? If you need more information or more code I'll gladly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To split items into chunks - use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
$chunks = array_chunk($your_data, 30);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    // send $chunk to endpoint
}
```

Comment: I didn't know this function! :O Works like a charm. I really appreciate your help! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrcount = ceil(count($requestarr['SelectionDetails'])/30);

for ($i=0; $i < $arrcount; $i++) { 
    $request['SelectionDetails'] = array_slice($requestarr['SelectionDetails'], $i * 30, 30);
    //call to endpoind and other code here....
}
```

`array_slice` can take a length argument longer than the array. You just have to move the starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :D Seems like a good answer, but I liked more u_mulders solution. Ill try his solution first.